# My code is acting weird, it is pulling information if statements when not told to

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently started learning Python, and the experience has been great, however, last night, I tried to make a simple program, and it is acting very strange

I have tried to change the locations of variables, and what they store/handle, and nothing I try seems to be working

```
def RF():

    user_type = input("Are you a new user? ")

    if user_type is "Yes" or "yes":
        ID = random.randrange(1, 999999)
        print("Your new ID Number is: " + str(ID))
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        ID = input("Account ID: ")
        writtingID = open('Acc info.txt', 'w')

        writtingID.write("ID: " + str(ID) + " | NAME: " + name + " | PASS: " + password)
        writtingID.close()
    elif user_type is "No" or "no":
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        ID = input("Account ID: ")


RF()
```

When the code is ran, I expect it to jump straight to asking for a name, but when I type "No" or "no", it for some reason runs the `print("Your new ID Number is: " + str(ID))` from a different `if` statement

Comment: `"Yes" or "yes" == "Yes"`

Comment: `if user_type is "Yes" or "yes":` needs to be `if user_type == "Yes" or user_type 
 == "yes":`, otherwise that statement is always true because `"yes"` is Truthy, also `is` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: `user_type = input("Are you a new user? ").lower()` lets you only compare against `'yes'`. Or you can do `if user_type in ["yes","Yes"]:`Do not use `is` to compare here - use `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `if user_type is "Yes" or "yes":` will always return true.

The reason for this is that the statement evaluates the same way as:

```
if (user_type is "Yes") or ("yes"):
```

The second parantheses (`"yes"`) will always return true. And as @Error-SyntacticalRemorse pointed out, you want to use `==` instead of `is` (see [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)).

Solution 1:

```
if user_type in ["Yes", "yes"]:
```

Solution 2:

```
if user_type.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
```

Comment: `(user_type is "Yes")` will also always evaluate to `False` (which the OP would catch only after fixing the first issue).

Comment: do not use `is` to compare in this situation - use `==`

Comment: Why would you not just use `str.lower()`?

Comment: Could the incorrect syntax for the if statements also be the reason why checking files was not working? Both of these functions were in the same script

Comment: @Matix i'm not sure how you implemented checking files worked. If you were looking at `Acc info.txt`, then that file would only exist if the `if` blocked executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    user_type = input("Are you a new user? ")

    if user_type in ("Yes", "yes"):
        ID = random.randrange(1, 999999)
        print("Your new ID Number is: " + str(ID))
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        ID = input("Account ID: ")
        writtingID = open('Acc info.txt', 'w')

        writtingID.write("ID: " + str(ID) + " | NAME: " + name + " | PASS: " + password)
        writtingID.close()
    elif user_type in ("No", "no"):
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        ID = input("Account ID: ")


RF()
```

Check if the word is in a tuple. For an easier approach, just use the `str.lower()` method to get rid of the extra complexity.

AKA:

```
if user_type.lower() == "yes":
    code
```

See [how to test multiple variables against a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value/15112149#15112149)

Comment: What is `elif user_type in ("No" or "no")` supposed to do?

Comment: That would check if user_type has the value "no" or "No".

Comment: You may want to test code before you paste it. `elif user_type in ("No", "no")` works completely different than `elif user_type in ("No" or "no")` which is the same as `elif user_type in (True)`

Comment: This is why I shouldn't post on SO while sleep deprived. Thank you for catching that mistake.

Comment: We all have those nasty typos. Python is to close to pseudo code :P